# How to Organize CSS with BEM?

Tags: css, bem

I just learned about BEM, and I want to organize my CSS with it. How do I organize my CSS with BEM? The BEM website doesn't tell you how to organize your CSS with BEM; the website just tells you how to name your BLOCKS, ELEMENTS, and MODIFIERS.

Also, should I use a different style sheet per web page, or should I use SASS and merge all my scss.files into one CSS file?

```css
/********************************
BLOCKS 
********************************/



/********************************
ELEMENTS
********************************/


/********************************
MODIFIERS
********************************/


or

/********************************
HEADER
********************************/


/********************************
MAIN SECTION 
********************************/


/********************************
FOOTER
********************************/



/********************************
MEDIA QUERIES
********************************/
```

Comment: I'd say use both. But honestly, do whatever makes sense to you, you're thinking on the right lines. Work the way you want to. Don't get too hung up on it. As long as you decide what each section is responsible for you'll keep your structure fairly clean.

Regarding SCSS, yeah use it, it helps keep things separated and preprocessors offer other ways to clean up the code.

Comment: @Sarcoma ok, thank you for the advice!

Comment: I recommend you to look into ITCSS if you have not already. It pretty much solved all my question when it comes to organize styles. Here is just one article https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try different approaches, and use whatever works best for you. Don't be afraid to experiment. If you're already comfortable with SASS, and want some inspiration, here's my usual strategy:

```
/* file: _block-name.scss */

.block { // selector for the block

  font-size: 12px; // example property

  &__element { // nested selector, equivalent to: 'block__element'

    background-color: white; // example property

    &--modifier { // nested selector, equivalent to: 'block__element--modifier'

      border: 2px solid red; // example property

    }

  }

}
```

Every block level element has its own file as an .scss partial. Nested selectors (provided by SASS) are used to target all elements and modifiers of that block.

This approach lends itself well to component-based frameworks like React (where each component is assigned its own BEM block-level selector), but it also works standalone.

If you look up BEM SASS in your search engine of choice you can find lots of other (perfectly valid) approaches to organizing your CSS with BEM. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question!

### What organization for your files?

We used to have one file per block with BEM. It's important for two reason:

1. When you see a class you already know in which file it is
2. It make it explicit that having a selector with two different blocks wrong, because you don't know where to place it

### What organization for your selectors?

I advice you to go from top (block) to bottom (elements), and to put alternative styles (modifiers, media-queries) directly after every block / elements. So:

```css
/* Footer.css */
/* Block */
.footer { }

/* Block modifiers */
.footer--dark { }

/* Block media-queries */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .footer { }
    .footer--dark { }
}

/* One element */
.footer__logo { }

/* One element modifiers */
.footer--dark .footer__logo { }

/* One element media-queries */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .footer__logo { }
    .footer--dark .footer__logo { }
}

/* another element */
/* ... */
```

### Should I use Sass nesting?

Be careful with the Sass imbrication, one of the answer advise you to nest your selector like this:

```
.footer {
    &--dark { }
}
```

It kind of harder to read, search, replace, etc. You probably will read it more times than you write it, so it could be a good choice to avoid it.

Here is a full pros/cons of sass nesting: http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/sass-selectors-to-nest-or-not-to-nest/

### What organization for your compiled files?

We usually provide only CSS file per website, its a better use of the browser cache. So you can group all your files when compiling with Sass.